# Forwarding Home Game-Server through GRE Tunnel | Can't ping remote GRE IPs

Tags: iptables, tunneling, ip-forwarding, gre

I am having trouble routing my game-servers through GRE. I do not receive a ping from either side when pinging them. I can ping the local GRE interface; however, I cannot ping the remote GRE interface.

*What I am attempting to do:*

I have a DDoS Protected IP from a service known as Vultr. I am attempting to route my game-server through the DDoS Protected IP from Vultr with a GRE tunnel. (I am running the Pterodactyl panel).

Here are the commands I have run on both servers:

**VPS (w/ DDoS Protected IP Address):**

`echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

`sysctl -p`

`iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local UNFILTERED_IP remote DESTINATION_SERVER_LOCAL_IP ttl 255`

`ip addr add 192.168.168.1/30 dev gre1`

`ip link set gre1 up`

**Destination Server (Game Server Host):**

`echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

`sysctl -p`

`iptunnel add gre1 mode gre local DESTINATION_SERVER_LOCAL_IP remote UNFILTERED_IP ttl 255`

`ip addr add 192.168.168.2/30 dev gre1`

`ip link set gre1 up`

I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough information; I am new to ServerFault and I am still learning this platform.

Also, I don't know what to attempt to troubleshoot as I am new to GRE Tunneling and was using a NAT Forward method beforehand.

Side Note: I am running this behind NAT if that means anything. I have properly opened the ports on my router to be available to the DDoS Protected server. I'm using ONLY public IPs for the remote IPs as I read that you need to do that if you're running behind NAT.

ANY Help is appreciated; Thank you so much!

Comment: `behind NAT`: so is `DESTINATION_SERVER_LOCAL_IP` configured to be the "DMZ" in the router that does the NAT? You must own a public IP on each side anyway, and "DMZ" might or might not work (I have never tried). If not, you probably need some sort of UDP encapsulation (and do port forwarding). See `ip-fou` and `ip-link` for `gre` for more details. (Not really sure about the difference between FOU and GUE.)

Comment: Btw to get to work with FOU/GUE you need to manually `modprobe fou`. Also see `man modules-load.d`.